# Android Studio Version Control (VCS) - How do I ignore files in Android Studio 3.6.x?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Prior to upgrading to Android Studio 3.6.1, I was able to keep files from being checked into VCS by using menu File-Settings-Version Control-Ignore Files

Ignored Files has been removed ( or moved ) and I can not find where to preform a similar action.

How do I ignore files in v3.6.x?

Here is an image from a previous version:

[image]

and here is an image from v3.6.1

[image]

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin - Okay - Thanks for the solicitation for points, again.

Comment: My answer is correct one? You haven't checked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ignored files" indeed was removed. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/07/support-for-vcs-ignores-in-intellij-idea-and-intellij-based-ides/ for more details.

Now the process of handling the VCS (Git, Mercurial, Subversion) ignored files is straightforward – simply add a file to the ignored file from either the Project Tree or the local changes tab of the VCS tool window.

Comment: how can I add any file or folder into ignore list? what is a way of doing that in android studio 4.1

Comment: @A.s.ALI first you need to make sure that the file in not under git already, then right click on a file -> Git -> Add to .gitignore